# Open default application for file and wait until it terminates

Tags: files, xdg, xdg-open

I tried to use `xdg-open` but it does not wait until the application terminates.

I also tried to get the MIME-type of the file with `xdg-mime query filetype fileHere` and using `xdg-mime query default MIME-type-here`.
If I use these two commands on a txt file for example, I get "org.gnome.gedit.desktop". I do not know however how I can start and wait for the application using this string.

Answer (score 1):

**Old Answer:**

I was able to determine the correct binary and call it directly by using the following steps:

1. Get the MIME-type with `xdg-mime query filetype fileHere` -> e.g. `text/plain`
2. Get the default app with `xdg-mime query default mimeHere` -> e.g. `org.gnome.gedit.desktop`
3. Lookup the `Exec=` line in the `app.desktop` file under `/usr/share/applications` -> e.g `Exec=gedit --new-document`
4. Call the correct binary and wait for it terminate -> e.g. `gedit`

**New Answer:**

You can use `mimeopen`.